# Passing vector to a thread function in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, vector

I am trying to run a multi-threaded matrix sum function, so that each line will sum up in a different thread. I have tried implementing all workarounds for passing vector to a cpp thread function in a template class but I still get this common error.

For the code:

```
template <typename T> class Matrix
{
    // variables for matrix size and variables in a one dimension vector
    unsigned int _rows;
    unsigned int _cols;
    vector<vector<T> > _matrix;

    // Matrix template class functions declarations (all common operators and constructors)

    void sumLine(vector<T>& first, vector<T>& second, vector<T>& result);
    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> & other) const;
};

 // Matrix template class functions implmentations

template <typename T> void Matrix<T>::sumLine(vector<T>& first, vector<T>& second, vector<T>& result)
{
    for (unsigned int colIdx = 0; colIdx < _cols; colIdx++)
    {
        result[colIdx] = first[colIdx] + second[colIdx];
    }
}

template <typename T> Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T> & other) const
{
    vector<thread> threads;
    vector<vector<T> > results;
    vector<T> newRow(_cols);
    results.resize(_rows, newRow);
    for (unsigned int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < _rows; rowIdx++)
    {
        vector<T> first = _matrix[rowIdx];
        vector<T> second = other._matrix[rowIdx];
        vector<T> result = results[rowIdx];
        threads.push_back(thread(Matrix<T>::sumLine, std::ref(first), std::ref(second), std::ref(result)));
    }
    for (unsigned int thrdIdx = 0; thrdIdx < _rows; thrdIdx++)
    {
        threads[thrdIdx].join();
    }

    // do something with vector<vector<T>> results
}
```

and still after compiling with gcc I get:

```
    In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/thread:39:0,
                 from Matrix.hpp:12,
                 from main.cpp:13:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/functional: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Matrix<Complex>::*)(std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&, std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&, std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&)>(std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >)>':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/thread:137:47:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Matrix<Complex>::*)(std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&, std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&, std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&); _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >}]'
Matrix.hpp:404:102:   required from 'Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T>&) const [with T = Complex]'
main.cpp:59:14:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/functional:1665:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Matrix<Complex>::*)(std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&, std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&, std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&)>(std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >)>'
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/functional:1695:9: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Matrix<Complex>::*)(std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&, std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&, std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >&)>(std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > >)>'
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

When Complex is a complex number class I wrote for the matrix template class, and my main function is trying to use this calculation with it. What is wrong here? If it is in the complex class, is there a simpler way to pass the parameters to the thread function to avoid this?

Comment: apart from the error, your code (as intended) is also wrong and inefficient. For example, you allocate all rows of the result matric and initialise all its elements is serial before starting the threads (instead, that could be part of the parallel code). Moreover, I would `emplace_back` each thread (rather than `push_back`). Finally (as pointed out in the answer already), your code does not actually compute the result matrix, since each result row is written into local variable and then discarded ...)

Answer (score 0):

you should post your Complex class, it may be the problem.

also in your code:

        `vector<T> first = _matrix[rowIdx];
        vector<T> second = other._matrix[rowIdx];
        vector<T> result = results[rowIdx];`

you should write it like this: `vector<T>& first = _matrix[rowIdx];`

because you are copying those vectors... or even `const vector<T>& first = _matrix[rowIdx];` if you don't modify them.

then you can remove the std::ref

Answer (score 0):

the following code compiles (with clang 3.5) and avoids passing references to temporaries to any `thread` ...

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;         // for expose only (don't do this in real code!!)
template <typename T> class Matrix
{
  using row = vector<T>;
  size_t _rows, _cols;
  vector<row> _matrix;
  Matrix(vector<row>&&); // defined elsewhere

  row sumLine(row const& first, row const& second) const
  {
    row result;                          // don't tempt the compiler to default
    result.reserve(_cols);               // initialise result[i] for all columns
    for(size_t c=0; c!=_cols; ++c)
      result.emplace_back(first[c]+second[c]);
    return result;                       // return is fast (no copy!)
  }

  Matrix<T> operator+ (const Matrix<T>& other) const;
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T>&other) const
{
  if(other._cols != _cols)
    throw std::runtime_error("column number mismatch in Matrix+Matrix");
  if(other._rows != _rows)
    throw std::runtime_error("row number mismatch in Matrix+Matrix");
  vector<thread> threads; threads.reserve(_rows);
  vector<row> result(_rows);
  for(size_t r=0; r!=_rows; ++r)
    threads.emplace_back([&,r]() {
        result[r] = Matrix<T>::sumLine(_matrix[r],other._matrix[r]);
      });
  for(size_t r=0; r!=_rows; ++r)
    threads[r].join();
  return move(result);
}

template class Matrix<double>;
```